# Read in individual words from text file and translate - C

Tags: c, file-io, c-strings

I am writing a program (for a class assignment) to translate normal words into their pirate equivalents (hi = ahoy).

I have created the dictionary using two arrays of strings and am now trying to translate an input.txt file and put it into an output.txt file.  I am able to write to the output file, but it only writes the translated first word over and over on a new line.

I've done a lot of reading/scouring and from what I can tell, using `fscanf()` to read my input file isn't ideal, but I cannot figure out what would be a better function to use. I need to read the file word by word (separated by space) and also read in each punctuation mark.

Input File:

```
Hi, excuse me sir, can you help
me find the nearest hotel? I
would like to take a nap and
use the restroom. Then I need
to find a nearby bank and make
a withdrawal.

Miss, how far is it to a local 
restaurant or pub?
```

Output: ahoy (46 times, each on a separate line)

Translate Function:

```
void Translate(char inputFile[], char outputFile[], char eng[][20], char pir[][20]){
char currentWord[40] = {[0 ... 39] = '\0'};

char word;

FILE *inFile;
FILE *outFile;

int i = 0;

bool match = false;

//open input file
inFile = fopen(inputFile, "r");


//open output file
outFile = fopen(outputFile, "w");


while(fscanf(inFile, "%s1023", currentWord) == 1){


    if( ispunct(currentWord) == 0){

        while( match != true){
            if( strcasecmp(currentWord, eng[i]) == 0 || i<28){ //Finds word in English array
                fprintf(outFile, pir[i]); //Puts pirate word corresponding to English word in output file
                match = true;
            }

            else {i++;}

        }
        match = false;
        i=0;

    }
    else{
        fprintf(outFile, &word);//Attempt to handle punctuation which should carry over to output


    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you start matching against different english words, `i<28` is initially true. Hence the expression `<anything> || i<28` is also immediately true and correspondingly the code will behave as though a match was found on the first word in your dictionary.

To avoid this you should handle the "found a match at index `i`" and the "no match found" condition separately. This can be achieved as follow:

```
if (i >= dictionary_size) {
  // No pirate equivalent, print English word
  fprintf(outFile, "%s", currentWord);
  break; // stop matching
}
else if (strcasecmp(currentWord, eng[i]) == 0){
  ...
}
else {i++;}
```

where `dictionary_size` would be 28 in your case (based on your attempt at a stop condition with `i<28`).

Comment: Thank you so much!  That fixed it straight away.  Also, thank you for also explaining why my code wasn't working.  Hopefully I can avoid this mistake in the future now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet that I use to parse things out. Here's what it does:

Given this input:

```
hi, excuse me sir, how are you.
```

It puts each word into an array of strings based on the DELIMS constant, and deletes any char in the DELIMS const. This will destroy your original input string though. I simply print out the array of strings:

```
[hi][excuse][me][sir][how][are][you][(null)]
```

Now this is taking input from stdin, but you can change it around to take it from a file stream. You also might want to consider input limits and such.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CHAR_LENGTH         100

const char *DELIMS = " ,.\n";
char *p;
int i;

int parse(char *inputLine, char *arguments[], const char *delimiters)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (p = strtok(inputLine, delimiters); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, delimiters))
    {
        arguments[count] = p;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    char line[1024];
    size_t bufferSize = 1024;

    char *args[CHAR_LENGTH];

    fgets(line, bufferSize, stdin);
    int count = parse(line, args, DELIMS); 
    for (i = 0; i <= count; i++){ 
        printf("[%s]", args[i]); 
    } 
}
```